# paperclipで作成したattachmentカラムをbulk updateする方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`gem 'activerecord-import'`
`gem 'paperclip'`
を使用してattachmentカラムを含むテーブルをbulk updateしようとしていますが、
`Missing column for value <photo>`
となってしまいます。
attachmentカラムをbulk updateすることは不可能なのでしょうか？

-- 追記 --
paperclipのモデル

```
include Paperclipable
  has_attached_file :photo, {
    styles: {
      w_100px: ["100x100>", :jpg],
    },
    default_url: 'http://dummyimage.com/100x100/eee/eee'
  }.merge(PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTIONS)
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, content_type:  /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

コントローラー

```
    spot_update_values = []
    params.require(:spots).map do |i, spot|
      spot_update_values << [ spot[:id].to_i, spot[:name], spot[:content], photo, article_content_id ]
    end
    Spot.import [ :id, :name_ja, :content_ja, :photo, :article_content_id ], spot_update_values, on_duplicate_key_update: [ :name_ja, :content_ja, :photo, :article_content_id ]
```

Comment: paperclip を使っている model, アップデートしようとした controller のコードなど、追記されると回答がされやすいと考えます。
ちなみに、`bulk update` は、`Hoge.where().update_all()` で出来ます。`activerecord-import` があるので、`bulk insert` に言及したい？と推察できますが、文脈とそぐわないので、判断できません。
質問を改善されると宜しいかと思います。

Comment: @user3758624
ご丁寧にありがとうございます。
アドバイス通り、追記してみました。

`「ちなみに、bulk updateは、Hoge.where().update_all()で出来ます。」`  
こちらのアドバイスですが、update_allは同じ値しか更新できないようなので、残念ながらこれは使えそうにありません...

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#usage
によれば、database のレコードは、下記の4つが使用されているようです。

> The basics of Paperclip are quite simple: Declare that your model has
>   an attachment with the has_attached_file method, and give it a name.
>
> Paperclip will wrap up to four attributes (all prefixed with that
>   attachment's name, so you can have multiple attachments per model if
>   you wish) and give them a friendly front end. These attributes are:
>
> <attachment>_file_name <attachment>_file_size
>   <attachment>_content_type <attachment>_updated_at

よって、photo ではなく、photo_file_name などにすれば、バルクアップデートは出来ると考えます。
ただ、更新はできますが、paperclip とは連携しないため、お望みの結果にはならないかもしれないと推察します。

PS. active-import で bulk update が可能であることを知らず失礼しました。